# Why is $|a-c|=|(a-b)+(b-c)| \ge |b-c|-|a-b|$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am interested in knowing how the author made the following implications listed.[image]

If we let $a=f(x)$, $b=g(x)$, and $c=g_1(x)$. Then why is $$|a-c|=|(a-b)+(b-c)| \ge |b-c|-|a-b|?$$

In general, I know $|a+b| \le |a|+|b|$ and $\big||a|-|b|\big|\le |a-b|$, but I am trying to work out the intermediate steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as the *reverse triangle inequality*, and is a direct consequence of the triangle inequality.

Indeed, we have
$$
\lvert b-c \rvert = \lvert (b-a)+(a-c) \rvert
\leq \lvert b-a \rvert+ \lvert a-c \rvert
$$
by the triangle inequality. Subtracting $\lvert b-a \rvert$ from both sides yields the result:
$$
\lvert b-c \rvert - \lvert b-a \rvert
\leq  \lvert a-c \rvert\,.
$$

Comment: This is just a work around for the question being asked. I am interested in knowing how the author made the implications listed.

Comment: How is that a workaround? (Also, note that you did edit your question after my answer). But to answer: the first equality is obvious, since $a-c=a-b+b-c$. The second is the reverse triangle inequality, which you can assume the authors know. It also is immediate from the last line you added after my answer, "In general I know that": look at the last inequality you wrote (it... is the reverse triangle inequality).

Comment: Note that what you wrote is $\lvert x-y\rvert \geq \lvert \lvert x\rvert - \lvert y\rvert\rvert$. This immediately implies $\lvert x-y\rvert \geq \lvert x\rvert - \lvert y\rvert$. Now plug in $x=b-c$, $y=a-b$.

Comment: But we can't say $|x-y|\ge |x|-|y|$. It is supposed to be $|x-y| \ge \big| |x|-|y| \big|$.

Comment: @AlJebr  We *can* say it. Since $A \leq \lvert A\rvert$ for every $A$, we have $\lvert x\rvert -\lvert y\rvert \leq \lvert \lvert x\rvert -\lvert y\rvert\rvert$.

Comment: Is it possible to expand on the steps in between $|(a-b)+(b-c)|\ge |b-c| - |a-b|$ without substituting? I know the triangle inequality and the reverse triangle inequality but I cannot seem to work out the intermediate steps.

Comment: @AlJebr  This is what my answer reproves. If you want to use directly the reverse triangle inequality, it gives $$\lvert (a-b)+(b-c)\rvert \geq \left\lvert \lvert a-b\rvert - \lvert b-c \rvert\right\rvert = \left\lvert\lvert b-c \rvert -  \lvert a-b\rvert\right\rvert \geq \lvert b-c \rvert -  \lvert a-b\rvert$$ the last inequality because (as pointed out above) $\lvert x\rvert \geq x$ for all $x$.

Comment: How did you get the first inequality?

Comment: @AlJebr That's exactly the reverse triangle inequality, applied to $x=a-b$ and $y=c-b$.

Comment: There are no sums in the reverse triangle inequality. It doesn't follow directly.

Comment: @AlJebr It does. *Make* the substitution I wrote above, you'll get $\lvert x-y\rvert$.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the triangle inequality, $|x+y| \le |x| + |y|$?

If so, substitute $x=a-c$ and $y=b-a$.

Answer (score 0):

The reverse triangle inequality states that $|x-y| \geq ||x|-|y||$ and the first equality is just because they rewrote the first expression i.e it really is equivalent for no other reason.